# Include in search model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone tell me what exactly this behavior generates:

```
 users = User.includes(:profile => [:city, :state])
```

particularly what means :city and :state and what is it different without these additional arguments.

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: it doesnt tell me what this values do

Comment: ok so this will include profiles where city and state == my values ,yes? its something like excluded  - before include profiles tables it check for right city and state value?

Comment: and of course when i do put this values for profiles => it will include every table of profiles ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you want your every users city and state to show in view, then without the `includes` method two database queries will be triggered for every user to fetch his `state` and `city` which introduces `n+1` query problem in you application. To resolve this you can eager load `state` and `city` by using `includes` method.

Answer (score 0):

this pre-caches 'city' and 'state' fields from linked table 'profiles' so there will be no extra queries when you call e.g 'user.profile.city'